# Why are ElasticBeanstalk .ebextensions ignored when using AWSJavaScriptSDK?

Tags: devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

When using the AWS JavaScript SDK to update an ElasticBeanstalk environment my `.ebextensions/*` are being ignored. I'm uploading the application source bundle as a .zip file to S3, which triggers a Lambda to deploy a new application version using this piece of code:

```js
const elasticbeanstalk = new AWS.ElasticBeanstalk();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const versionLabel = "myVersionString" + (new Date().toUTCString());

  // elasticbeanstalk.createApplicationVersion [...]

  elasticbeanstalk.updateEnvironment({
    "EnvironmentName": "myEBEnvironment",
    "VersionLabel": versionLabel
  });

};
```

When uploading the same source bundle within the AWS management console, all my `.ebextensions` are being executed as expected.

There is nothing special inside of the *.config files. I'm just creating a few files based on environment variables to use later, e.g.

```yaml
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/prepare_key.sh":
    mode: "000777"
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash

      if [ -z ${MY_KEY+x} ]
      then
          echo "MY_KEY is not set. skip."
      else
          echo "prepare MY_KEY ..."
          echo $MY_KEY > /home/ec2-user/key
      fi
container_commands:
  set_up:
    command: "/home/ec2-user/prepare_key.sh"
```

As a result the file `/home/ec2-user/prepare_key.sh` is not being generated (or updated) and the command `set_up` is not being executed during the Lambda deploy.

I double checked the source bundles. All my `.ebextensions/*.config` files are there. There are no `.ebignore` files in my project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VersionLabel` cannot contain a comma.

In the Lambda I was using `new Date().toUTCString()` which is being appended to a static version label. This results in a string like `"myVersionString Mon, 09 Sep 2019 08:16:23 GMT"`. The included comma caused `.ebextensions` not being properly extracted by Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm now appending just an ISO String, which does not contain any commas.

```
const versionLabel = "myVersionString" + (new Date().toISOString());
```